# Call API only after setting loading state

Tags: reactjs

Since, setState in a functional component do not return a promise, how do we set a loading state and then call an API. I have seen people doing it like the one below. I think the axios call will not wait for the loading state to be successfully set before executing. Is there any other better way to solve this without writing the fetch part in an useEffect with the dependency of the loading state?

```
 useEffect(() => {
    const fetchProduct = async () => {
      setLoading(true);
      try {
        const response = await axios('http://localhost/products');
        setData(response.data);
      } catch (err) {
        setError(err);
      }
      setLoading(false);
    };

    fetchProduct();
  
  }, [productId]);
```

Comment: If your component requires data from the external API to render you can set `loading` to true by default?

Comment: I see. Forget about the useEffect and let's say I need to call the API with a button click. In this case, the `loading` state will determine whether the button will be disabled or not. So, if the state is not set to true before calling the API, user might be able to click the button multiple times. This in turn will make multiple fetches.

Answer (score 0):

you can try something like this

```
useEffect(() => {
const fetchProduct = async () => {
    setLoading(true);
    await axios.get('http://localhost/products')
        .then(response => {
            setLoading(false);
            setData(response.data);
        }).catch(error => {
            setLoading(false);
            setError(error);
        })
};

fetchProduct();

 }, [productId]);
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I am actually worried about another situation. Let's say I need to call the API with a button click. In this case, the loading state will determine whether the button will be disabled or not. So, if the state is not set to true before calling the API, user might be able to click the button multiple times. This in turn will make multiple fetches. Any idea to go about this situation?

Comment: you can user loading state as disabled attribute of the button for example
<button disabled={loading} />

Comment: That's what I am doing now. My concern is, since `setLoading` is not synchronous, the fetch call will be executed on button click before the `loading` state actually changes and disables the button. This will allow the user to click the button multiple times briefly.

Comment: How can I use the same solution on POST ?

Comment: @ManassehCodes
you can use axios.post